# Disabling email when using Add-Member

Tags: powershell, powerapps

I am attempting to add users to a PowerApps while reading from an excel file Everything works but the default behavior is to send an email to a new user when added. I cannot figure out how to disable the "Send email to new user" with my script. Basically, the script grabs all the info from the csv file and adds the user using their email address.

```
foreach($user in (import-csv -Path $CsvPath)) {
    $UserAppName = $User.AppName
    $result = Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "PrincipalEmail" -value $user.AppName -Force
}
```